# Fiber glass In Attic. need knowledge

Tags: insulation, safety

I have been seeing some dust of Fiberglass(?) floating in the air. Is breathing it, in unhealthy? I was unaware of the equipment in the attic, which I discover all the wrong  wiring connections from the lights. i have work as a electrician and i have never see anything like this. Alot of fiberglass and tapes.

Comment: To be honest, im very concern of my health,,. i know very well that i have no knowledge. i need physical help. i dont believe that its a situation i can help people to help me .. im on section eight. one other thing.  Ungodly situation i say.. please respond. i be

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's fiberglass?  It very well could be any number of types of insulation, but you want to make sure it is not an asbestos material or made with asbestos.  Even if you are sure it is not asbestos, wear a respirator with a P100 type filter.  This will ensure that you are protected from any hazardous particles.  A dust mask will not protect you enough, especially if you have no idea what the dust is.

Comment: how can u tell what it is. u see im waiting on an inspection to come check it out. im very curious about this situation. i